# NIO Server not scaling

Tags: java, netty, nio

I build a simple `NIO Server` and a Client code to test it.
My previous SO questions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473163/nio-client-giving-exception-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-no) and [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571829/10000-concurrent-connection-using-java-nio) (Client in question 1)

As per previous suggestions I updated my Server code to accept faster and also passed argument for Backlog Queue size to `public void bind(SocketAddress endpoint,int backlog)` method.

But still I am not able to scale my Server above 10k clients.
The Server is a simple Echo Server and 10k client also when I connect clients at rate of 50 clients per 5 sec.
I am not limited by hardware . So what I am missing ?

If somebody who have wrote servers handling more clients can they please explain what I may be doing wrong and if possible share their codes or on-line resources  which can help.

Also today I started reading about `Netty` and found many good responses.

If I am not able to scale using simple `Java NIO` will Netty be of any help ?
Will `Netty` help to increase no of connected Clients ?

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edit** :
This Question is partially similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571829/10000-concurrent-connection-using-java-nio) but here I ask some part of previous question to clarify that if I am not able to scale using basic Java NIO
still will switching to Netty help ?

Server :
`

```
public class Server implements Runnable  {

public final static String ADDRESS = "192.168.2.14";

public final static int PORT = 8511;

public final static long TIMEOUT = 10000;

public int clients;

ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);

private ServerSocketChannel serverChannel;

private Selector selector;

private Map<SocketChannel,byte[]> dataTracking = new HashMap<SocketChannel, byte[]>();

public Server(){
    init();
}

private void init(){
    System.out.println("initializing server");

    if (selector != null) return;
    if (serverChannel != null) return;

    try {
        selector = Selector.open();
        serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(ADDRESS, PORT));
        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Now accepting connections...");
    try{
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

            int ready = selector.select();
            if(ready==0)
                continue;
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

            while (keys.hasNext()){
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()){
                    continue;
                }

                if (key.isAcceptable()){
                    System.out.println("Accepting connection");
                    accept(key);
                }

                if (key.isWritable()){
                    System.out.println("Writing...");
                    write(key);
                }

                if (key.isReadable()){
                    System.out.println("Reading connection");
                    read(key);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        closeConnection();
    }

}

private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException{

    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    byte[] data = dataTracking.get(channel);
    dataTracking.remove(channel);
    **int count = channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(data));
    if(count == 0)
    {
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        return;
    }
    else if(count > 0)
    {
        key.interestOps(0);
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ);  
    }** 
}

private void closeConnection(){

    System.out.println("Closing server down");
    if (selector != null){
        try {
            selector.close();
            serverChannel.socket().close();
            serverChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void accept(SelectionKey key) throws IOException{
    ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
    SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
    if(socketChannel == null)
    {
        throw new IOException();
    }
    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
     clients++;
    **//socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE|SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    SelectionKey skey = socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);**

    byte[] hello = new String("Hello from server").getBytes();
    dataTracking.put(socketChannel, hello);
}

private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException{
    SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    readBuffer.clear();
    int length;
    try {
        length = channel.read(readBuffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Reading problem, closing connection");
        System.out.println("No of clients :"+clients);
        key.cancel();
        channel.close();
        return;
    }
    if (length == -1){
        System.out.println("Nothing was there to be read, closing connection");
        channel.close();
        key.cancel();
        return;
    }

    readBuffer.flip();
    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
    readBuffer.get(data, 0, length);
    String fromclient = new String(data,0,length,"UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Received: "+fromclient);
    String dat = fromclient+channel.getRemoteAddress();
    data= dat.getBytes();
    echo(key,data);
}

private void echo(SelectionKey key, byte[] data) throws IOException{
    SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    dataTracking.put(socketChannel, data);
    **//key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    try
    {
        write(key);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem in echo"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    Thread serv = new Thread(new Server());
    serv.start();
   }

}
```

Comment: `Will netty help?` It'll at least be tested and production ready code, whereas anything you attempt may be buggy in numerous ways.

Comment: @Kayaman : But my main focus is on increasing no of connections.
Will netty help in that ? or better performance ?

Comment: There's an excellent way to find that out. Try it.

Comment: @Kayaman
Yes finally I will be. But I want to know from people who have used both or  who know which might be better.Also here using java nio I am unable to handle 10k+ clients , I want to know what I am doing wrong .

Comment: Well it wouldn't take long to whip up a similar echo server with netty and see whether there's a difference. It can take a long time to wait for a good answer to such a broad question.

Comment: Here,  as you say yourself, you are re-asking a question you have already asked before. It is therefore a duplicate. Don't do that. Twice this week.

Comment: @EJP
Only some part is similar that too just to clarify that I was unable to scale using Java NIO doing what and thus will Netty help ?
I think it is good to explain what I have done and was unable to do and then ask what should I go for ?