# java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

Tags: java, nio

Now today I was testing Server and Client code on different machine.
Both were on same Wi-fi network.

I created clients using below code and got this exception for many threads :

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
    at SocketTest.connect(Client.java:188)
    at SocketTest.run(Client.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

the line 73 is `connect(key)` 
and line 188 is `if(!(channel.finishConnect()))`

So the client thread was unable to connect because no reply came from server ? Right ?

Question)When I run both Server and Client on same machine localhost this exception does not arise. What may be the reasons ? (network problem ?).

Also I also use Backlog queue parameter in public void bind(SocketAddress endpoint,int backlog) as 2000. While exact size is unknown(around 200 ?) but I am using a large value so that maximum value will be used.(Right ? or Java will make a queue ?).

Can this be a reason : The Server puts the request in backlog queue and till it gets time to serve it, the timeout may have happened at Client ?

Client :

```
public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n=100;
    SocketTest [] st= new SocketTest[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        st[i]= new SocketTest("hi");


    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i%50 == 0)
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            System.out.println(""+ie);
        }
        new Thread(st[i]).start();

    }
}
}
class SocketTest implements Runnable {

    private String message = "";
    ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1000);
    private Selector selector;
    private int i;
    public static AtomicInteger cnt= new AtomicInteger(0);

    public SocketTest(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SocketChannel channel;
        try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            channel = SocketChannel.open();
            channel.configureBlocking(false);

            channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);

            channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.10", 8511));

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                selector.select();

                Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                while (keys.hasNext()){
                    SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                    keys.remove();

                    if (!key.isValid()) continue;

                    if (key.isConnectable()){  
                            connect(key);
                        System.out.println("I am connected to the server");
                    }   
                    if (key.isWritable()){
                        write(key);
                    }
                    if (key.isReadable()){
                        read(key);
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
        catch(ClosedByInterruptException e)
        {
            // let go of thread
        }
        catch(CancelledKeyException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("IOE Occured|maybe Server died");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    private void close(){

        try {
                if(selector!=null)
                    selector.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) 
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    private void read (SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        readBuffer.clear();
        int length;
        try{
        length = channel.read(readBuffer);

        } catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Reading problem, closing connection for  : "+channel.getLocalAddress());
            key.cancel();
            channel.close();
            return;
        }
        if (length == -1){
            System.out.println("Nothing was read from server");
            channel.close();
            key.cancel();
            return;
        }
        readBuffer.flip();
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        readBuffer.get(buff, 0, length);
        //length=buff.length;

        String fromserver = new String(buff,0,length,"UTF-8");
        length = fromserver.length();
        System.out.println("Server said: "+fromserver);

        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
    }

    private void write(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
        i++;
        message = "location now "+i;
        if(i==2)
        {
            cnt.addAndGet(1);
            System.out.println("****"+cnt.get()+"****");
        }

        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie)
        {
            System.out.println(""+ie);
            //Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        //assuming all goes in one shot
        channel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes()));

        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ/*|SelectionKey.OP_WRITE*/);
    }

    private void connect(SelectionKey key){
        SocketChannel channel= (SocketChannel) key.channel();

        try
        {
            if(!(channel.finishConnect())){
                //System.out.println("* Here *");
                return;
            }
        }
        catch(ConnectException e){
            System.out.println("Conect Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
            try{channel.close();}
            catch(IOException ie){ie.printStackTrace();key.cancel();return;}
            return;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("BP 1"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            try{channel.close();}
            catch(IOException ie){ie.printStackTrace();key.cancel();return;}
            return;
        }
            //channel.configureBlocking(false);
            //channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);

    }
}
```

Comment: [Why does this code still contain all the same errors I have already told you about a week ago?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30473569/207421)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NIO client giving exception : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473163/nio-client-giving-exception-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused-no)

Comment: @wforums

This question is different from that one.In that one the **connection refused** was the problem here **connection timed out**.

Comment: @cruxioneffux Nevertheless, when you post exactly the same, uncorrected, code from a previous question, people are apt to look on it as a duplicate, and the people who gave you all the corrections and commentary are apt to get peeved and wonder why they bother, and also to wonder why you post here if you're just going to ignore everything you're told. All of which would be avoided if you had ***bothered to fix the code.*** Why haven't you?

Comment: @EJP
Sorry for this.
Well I am having many version of client codes which all perform same, so pasted anyone(which I was using ) .I made most changes you suggested and that code is now pasted above .Please see.

Comment: I can still see at least two of the errors I mentioned. I'm not really interested in discussing code I have already provided corrections for.

Comment: @EJP
I know you are busy solving many problems and its difficult to discuss codes.
While you say you see atleast 2 suggestions I tried to follow all.
Except these 2 :
1.Ignoring the counts returned
2.Display of the String received

I didn't forget any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connect timed out because the server didn't reply.

> When I run both Server and Client on same machine localhost this exception does not arise. What may be the reasons ? (network problem ?).

Why **should** it arise? The server is there, the client is there, no network problems in between. The question doesn't make sense.

> Also I also use Backlog queue parameter in public void bind(SocketAddress endpoint,int backlog) as 2000. While exact size is unknown(around 200 ?) but I am using a large value so that maximum value will be used. Right?

Right.

> or Java will make a queue?

I don't know what this means. Java doesn't do anything with the backlog parameter. It goes straight to TCP.

> Can this be a reason: The Server puts the request in backlog queue and till it gets time to serve it, the timeout may have happened at Client ?

No. Only *completed* connections go on the backlog queue.

Comment: I read this :

Connection timeouts occur when:

1.The IP address for the requested server is successfully found
2.Connection establishment packets are dispatched to the IP address
3.The destination address deliberately ignores or does not receive them

Similar to connection timeout is Connection Refused, but in this case the destination system is actually sending packets back saying "go away" No service available for you.

Is it correct ?
So here Server doesn't get request ?

Comment: It didn't reply. That's all we know. Maybe it didn't get the request: maybe the reply got lost.

Comment: So this did not happen on localhost and happened on Network .
So its a network problem.Correct ?
Now reason maybe Congestion ? Router problem ?